# Proper Timer Behavior using navigating between tab screens (React Native Typescript Hooks)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am in the early stages of learning react native along with `TypeScript` and react-navigation. I am trying to implement a countdown timer app with editable time and labels. I was able to get most of the behaviors I'm wanting to work correctly but the last thing I'm stuck on is I want the timer to reset to the input value when the go button is pressed. other comments on the capabilities of the timer are in the comments of `app.tsx`.

Along with assistance with this functionality, any input on better ways of doing this or more appropriate standards I should have in my code would be appreciated.

link to the snack if that works: https://snack.expo.io/@jpb159/two-tap-timer

**app.tsx**

```
// In App.js in a new project

// React Navigation v5, Hooks, Interval and Typescript Practice
// Timer app counting down in secconds until the time reaches 0
// -  Countdown should continue until either time reaches 0 or the 'go' button is pressed.
// -  Should reset the 'time' to the entered 'time value' every time the 'go' button is pushed then continue counting down to 0.
// -  No reset should happen when tabs are selected using bottomTabNav. 
// -  Initial timer screen values are id= -1, timerName= "initial name", duration= 0, time= 0.


import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import AppTabs from './src/Navigation'

function App() {
  return (
    <AppTabs />
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navigation.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, StackNavigationProp  } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import EditScreen from '../Screens/EditScreen';
import TimerScreen, { TimerProps } from '../Screens/TimerScreen';

type HomeStackParamList = {
  HomeScreen: undefined;
  EditScreen: undefined;
};
type TimerStackParamList = {
  TimerScreen: { id:number|undefined, timerName: string; duration: number } | undefined;
};

type TimerScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<TimerStackParamList, 'Timer Screen'>;

type TimerScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  TimerStackParamList,
  'Timer Screen'
>;

export type NavProps = {
  navigation: TimerScreenNavigationProp,
  route: TimerScreenRouteProp,
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator<HomeStackParamList>();
const TimerStack = createStackNavigator<TimerStackParamList>();

function HomeTab({ route } : NavProps) {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Home Screen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        initialParams={{
          timerName: "timer 1",
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Edit Screen" component={EditScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function TimerTab({ route } : NavProps) {
  const props = route.params.params ?  route.params.params : {id:".params.params undefined",timerName:".params.params undefined", duration:".params.params undefined"}
  console.log(
    "--TIMER TAB-\n"
    +"\t-id: "+props.id
    +"\t-timerName: "+props.timerName
    +"\t-duration: "+props.duration
  );
  return (
    <TimerStack.Navigator>
      <TimerStack.Screen 
        name="Timer Screen" 
        initialParams={{...props, id:-1}} 
        component={TimerScreen}
      />
        

    </TimerStack.Navigator>
  );
}

type TabParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Timer:
    | {
        screen: 'Timer Screen';
        params: { timerName: string; duration: number };
      }
    | undefined;
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>();

const AppTabs = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Tab.Screen name="Home Tab" component={HomeTab} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Timer Tab" component={TimerTab} 
          initialParams={{            
            params:{
              id: -1,
              timerName: "initial name",
              duration: 0,
              stop: true
            }
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppTabs;
```

**Home Screen** where the timer name and time are editable and where the go button navigates to the timer screen along with params

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavProps } from '../src/Navigation';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }: NavProps) {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState<string>();
  const [val, onChangeVal] = React.useState<string>();

  const [date, setDate] = useState<any>(new Date(1598051730000));
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<any>('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onChange = (event: any, selectedDate: any) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode: string) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };

  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode('time');
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'column',
          width: '90%',
          padding: '1%',
          borderWidth: 10,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: '90%',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          }}>
          <Text> Label: </Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="'Timer Name...'"
            value={text}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: '90%',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          }}>
          <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
          {show && (
            <DateTimePicker
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              value={date}
              mode={mode}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          )}
          <Button title="Go" 
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(
                "HOME SCREEN-\n"
                +"\t-id: "+1
                +"\t-timerName: "+text
                +"\t-duration: "+val
              );
              navigation.navigate('Timer Tab', {
                screen: 'Timer Screen',
                params:{
                  id: 1,
                  timerName: text,
                  duration: Number(val),
                  stop: false
                }
              });
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text> time value: </Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="'enter time value...'"
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            value={val}
            onChangeText={onChangeVal}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
{/*
      <Text> other buttons:</Text>
      <Button
        title="Timer Screen"
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('timer duration: ' + route.params.duration),
            navigation.navigate('Timer Tab',
              {screen:'Timer Screen', 
                params:{
                  id:0
                } 
              }
            );
        }}
      />

      <Button
        title="Edit Screen"        
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Edit Screen');
        }}
      />
*/}      
    </View>

  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Timer Screen** where the countdown is displayed and should run until 0 (then console.logs 'timer done') or the 'go' button is pressed again resetting the time left

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavProps } from '../src/Navigation';

export type TimerProps={
  isPaused: boolean,
}

function TimerScreen({ route, navigation }: NavProps, props: TimerProps) {
  const { id, timerName, duration, stop } = route.params;
  
  const [initTime, setInitTime] = useState<number>(duration);
  const [time, setTime] = useState<number>(duration);
  const [isStopped, setIsStopped] = useState<boolean>(stop);

  console.log(
    "----TIMER SCREEN-\n"
    +"\t-id: "+id
    +"\t-timerName: "+timerName
    +"\t-duration: "+duration
    +"\t-initTime: "+initTime
    +"\t-stop: "+isStopped
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(initTime !== duration){
      console.log("***duration changed!!!"); 
      setTime(duration)
      setInitTime(duration)
    }

    console.log('time:'+time);
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      // console.log('time:'+time);
      if(!props.isPaused){
          setTime(time-1);
          
      }
      else{console.log('timer paused: '+props.isPaused)}
    }, 1000)
    if(time<=0||time === null||time === undefined){ 
      console.log('Timer Done timerId:'+timerId);
      setIsStopped(true);
      if(timerId) {
        // setInitTime(0);
        clearInterval(timerId);
      } 
      return; 
    }

    // const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    //   console.log('focussed');
    //   setTime(route.params.duration);
    // });
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [time, duration, initTime, isStopped, props.isPaused,])


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Timer Screen {"id:"+id}</Text>
      <Text>timerName: {JSON.stringify(timerName)}</Text>
      <Text>duration: {JSON.stringify(duration)}</Text>
      <Text>time: {time}</Text>
      
      
      <View></View>
      <Button
        title="Timer Screen again"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.push('Timer Screen', {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          });
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to Home"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Home Tab', { screen: 'Home Screen' })
        }
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
      <Button
        title="Go back to first screen in stack"
        onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default TimerScreen;
```